# USB3 Hard Drive Not Recognised by Linux

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, gentoo, usb-drive

My external USB 3 hard drive is behaving very strangely:

- If I plug it into a USB 2 port, it works fine
- If I plug it into a USB 3 port, it doesn't work at all.  It's not even mentioned in `/var/log/messages`.
- If I plug a USB 2 device (memory stick) into the same USB 3 port, it works fine.
- I *think* the USB 3 drive is mentioned in `dmesg` during boot up when it's plugged into the USB 3 port, but it's hard to tell.  There are no clear device names listed, just serial ids etc.

The last time I used it on this machine, everything was alright, but that was at least a month ago.  Since then I've gone through a few kernel upgrades and a number of package updates.  My guess is something went wrong in the process, so I'm here to try and narrow that down.

Useful information:

- I'm running Gentoo (kernel version: 3.7.4-gentoo)
- `CONFIG_USB_STORAGE` is enabled in the kernel (obviously, since USB 2 works)
- `CONFIG_USB_XHCI_HCD` is also enabled in the kernel

The hardware involved is:

- Lenovo X1 laptop
- WD 1tb portable drive.  There's no external power options, and I've never needed one (when it was working)

Comment: Is there a more precise name for the drive, "WD 1tb portable drive" does not give much info?

Comment: I would suggest pastebinning your dmesg

Comment: In an effort to figure out what was going on, I enabled xhci debugging in the kernel, rebooted, and magically it worked!  Then, as a test, I disabled debugging and it worked again :-(

I think I may just have a flakey drive on my hands: `Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1058:1042 Western Digital Technologies, Inc.`

I guess it's appropriate to delete this question now?

Comment: @DanielQuinn, better answer your own question with what you found out, and accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a lot of toying with this, it started to work, though for the life of me I can't figure out why.  Here's a list of things I tried:

- Didn't work

  - Rebooting
  - Unplugging and plugging it back in while the laptop is running
  - Booting up with it plugged in
  - Plugging it in post-boot up
  - Recompiling my kernel with the same options
- Did work

  - Recompiling my kernel with USB3 debuging enabled
  - Re-recompiling my kernel with USB3 debugging turned off

So basically I tried recompiling my kernel with debugging enabled to see what was wrong, and lo-and-behold it worked perfectly.  Then, as an experiment, I recompiled again, this time with debugging *off*, and it *still* worked.

I have no idea what happened, but for those who might come here in search of an answer one day, I offer you what I have.